# Use firebase click_action in PWA

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I have successfully implemented Firebase in my PWA to receive notifications when the app is on the background or closed.

But when I click on the push notification the app opens on the `start_url` of the `manifest.json`-file. How can I open a specific page in my PWA when a push-notification is clicked?

I already tried using `click_action` but without luck:

```
{
    "notification":{
        "click_action": "/my-page"
    },
  "data":{
    "title":"Test",
    "message":"test"
  }, "to":"TOKEN"
}
```

Also tried `fcm_options.link`:

```
{
    "webpush": {
      "fcm_options": {
        "link": "https://my.app/my-page"
      }
    },
  "data":{
    "title":"Test",
    "message":"test"
  }, "to":"TOKEN"
}
```

Both get ignored and the app just opens on the `start_url`.

This is my `firebase-messaging-sw.js`:

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here. Other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
firebase.initializeApp({
    //...
});


// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log(
    '[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ',
    payload
  );
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.message,
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Maybe I can add some action-click in `notificationOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add **actions** array according to the documentation of showNotifications library.

In previous one of my project, I followed this : [Documentation of ShowNotification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification)

like this below code :

```
const notificationOptions = { 
  body: payload.data.message, 
  actions: [ { action: 'open_page', title: 'Page Open' } ] 
};
```